# Adverbial modifier after than?

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions, adverbial-phrases

I read a sentence as follows from a book by a Harvard professor(born in the U.S.A.):

> Despite the fact that farming required more strenuous physical exertion than most urban jobs, the rural grain ration was set lower than in the cities.

I wonder if the last clause is grammatical since it is an adverbial modifier that follows `lower than`. I have never read such a combination before, and I thought `lower than that in the cities` seems more natural-sounding.

I read some articles about comparative constructions, for example [this](https://academicguides.waldenu.edu/writingcenter/grammar/comparisons) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/80777/10484), and have not found a sentence with a similar structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a native speaker but not a grammarian, the original sentence is fine.  Your version also makes sense but the `that` is unnecessary making the original slightly preferable.

The comparison is between the grain ration in rural areas and the grain ration in cities.  By not mentioning `grain ration` again or `that`, it is implicit that the same item is being compared in the two areas.